# How to design application server for WPF clients (connecting via internet, using wcf or something else)

Tags: wpf, wcf

I have developed LOB client/server app in WPF (MVVM, Entity Framework, PostgreSQL).

And now I am trying to learn and understand how to upgrade same project to something like 3 tier but via internet. (transfer BL and DAL into some intermediate server/service)

Do you think WCF is good for this job (if so please explain basic concept), or is there some kind of framework out there which would make all this a little bit easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I do think that WCF, generally speaking, can easily take the role of business layer and data access layer. You should read a good book on WCF or architecture, because a post on Stack Overflow is not enough to explain it in detail.

Comment: Maybe just a basic concept... how would this work? Do you think this requires a lot of changes to basic project? Any advice at all...